# Geoserver Postgres Configuration

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap

My imported postgres database size for plane.osm is more than 300GB under slim mode.

It added four tables for Tiles Creation.

*planet_osm_line, planet_osm_road, planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_point*

Each Table contains attributes which are:

> osm_id
>    access
>    addr:housename
>    addr:housenumber
>    addr:interpolation 
>    admin_level
>    aerialway
>    aeroway
>    amenity
>    area
>    barrier
>    bicycle
>    brand
>    bridge
>    boundary
>    building
>    construction
>    covered
>    culvert
>    cutting
>    denomination
>    disused
>    embankment
>    foot
>    generator:source
>    harbour
>    highway
>    historic
>    horse
>    intermittent
>    junction
>    landuse
>    layer
>    leisure
>    lock
>    man_made
>    military
>    motorcar
>    name
>    natural
>    office
>    oneway
>    operator
>    place
>    population
>    power
>    power_source
>    public_transport
>    railway
>    ref
>    religion
>    route
>    service
>    shop
>    sport
>    surface
>    toll
>    tourism
>    tower:type
>    tracktype
>    tunnel
>    water
>    waterway
>    wetland
>    width
>    wood
>    z_order
>    way_area
>    way

Now I want to configure it to Geoserver for a specific attribute.

Example: in polygon, I need to import `building` alone.

I am following this [GeoServer and OpenStreetMap](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/) and [Publishing a PostGIS Table](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html) but it's not specificly clear about the above.

I need to know if it's possible in Geoserver? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your layer as SQL View - [link to the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)

For your case (buildings), the SQL statement for filtering will be:

```
SELECT * FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE building IS NOT NULL
```

And then, publish the layer as usual.

Comment: And for improving the speed you may want to create an index on osm_polygon table for the building column.

Comment: @user30184 i cant index planet_osm_polygon's building attribute because it may contain duplicate values.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with indexing a non-unique column in Postgres. Just don't try to put unique constraint on it.